# AngularJS - Display files from FTP server and download link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ftp

Have an FTP server set up with a number of files. Would like to create an AngularJS page (hosted on a different server) that allows user to click on a link on the angular page and download file(s) directly to the users local machine.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a handy app. What have you got so far?

Comment: ..got a bald spot from scratchin my head!! :) I do have a server script that connects and reads in the file(s), but not able to 'return' that to angular page.